# Error while building Project in Visual Studio (Multiple assemblies)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, xamarin.android, windows-runtime

when i try to build my Project I get the following error:

> Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\asdfrom1337\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.4.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.  asdfrom1337 C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\asdfrom1337\asdfrom1337\CSC  1   Active

I tried to remove "one of the references" (there is only one) in the Project but then I get more errors.

Can someone help me please?

[image: References]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36978905-rx-net-3-0-with-xamarin-android help?